# remove/ignore css declaration or rule WITHOUT javascript

Tags: css

I'm guessing the answer is "no", but I'll ask anyway. Is there a CSS property/value that allows you to remove or ignore a previous CSS declaration or rule? Example:

```
<div class="foo">whatever</div>
```

```
div {background: red;}
.foo {background: blue;}
.foo:hover {background: <something-that-will-let-it-default-back-to-red>;}
```

Values of `inherit`, `initial`, `unset`, or `revert` do not work for this. The idea is to avoid the need to explicitly set it back to the style it would have had if the rule had not existed. Using a CSS variable would also be explicit. With Javascript, one could just toggle the "foo" class on hover. I'm just wondering if there's a way to do something similar with CSS only, even if it's only being considered as part of a CSS draft proposal.

Comment: Not an exact match (and thus not posting as an answer) but a different approach that would still allow some degree of abstraction here would be to leverage [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) instead.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Yeah, as I said in my post, CSS variables would still be explicit. I thought of a solution, though: `.foo:not(:hover) {background: blue;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't exactly "remove" a previous CSS declaration/rule, but it does have the net effect that I was looking for.

```css
div {background: red;}
.foo:not(:hover) {background: blue;}
```

```html
<div class="foo">whatever</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
div {background: red;}
.foo {background: blue;}
.foo:hover {background: red !important;}
```

Comment: _"The idea is to avoid the need to explicitly set it back to the style it would have had if the rule had not existed."_

Comment: Oh i see, sorry my bad :/